# Efficient loading of a csv file in pandas with different sep or comp

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have many csv files on s3. Some have gzip compression, some don't. The same with semicolon vs comma as a separator.

What is an efficient way to 'feel' the files and load them? I now use double try/except loops but that is probably not the best way.

When the file simply does not exist the error is also unclear.

When instead of loading the ['Body'] from boto3 I use the s3:// address, my gzip sniffer does not work.

```
with open(filepath, 'rb') as test_f:
    gzip = binascii.hexlify(test_f.read(2)) == b'1f8b'
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of suggestions, not sure you might have considered these.

1. Have you tried pandas.read_csv ([read_csv documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)) with compression parameter = 'infer'?
2. Alternatively try getting extension of filenames and confirm with if conditions for known filesizes and handle unknown/unexpected ones in a separate else block. This is definitely not optimal and works better only if you really know the expected file extensions.

Comment: Hello Anand, thanks for the ideas. By default Pandas infers the compression based on the extension. That is probably the solution for me; go through all files and change the file names to gzip specific. If that is sorted the difference between , and ; is not so hard.